# ParserError when using AppendHeader

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I'm calling a method that I expect to let a user download a file from my server:

```
string path = MapPath(filePath);
     string name = Path.GetFileName(path);
     string ext = Path.GetExtension(path);
     string type = "";
     // set known types based on file extension  
     if (ext != null) {
        switch (ext.ToLower()) {
           case ".pdf":
              type = "Application/pdf";
              break;
        }
     }
     Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition",
         "attachment; filename=" + name);

     if (type != "") {
        Response.ContentType = type;
     }
     Response.WriteFile(path);
     Response.End();
```

I get the following error:

Foutdetails webpagina

Gebruikersagent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Tijdstempel: Mon, 17 Oct 2011 14:09:42 UTC

Bericht: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Het bericht dat is ontvangen van de server, is niet **geparseerd**. Vaak wordt dit probleem veroorzaakt door het feit dat het antwoord is aangepast met aanroepen naar Response.Write(), antwoordfilters, HttpModules, of door het feit dat servertracering is ingeschakeld.
Details: Er is een fout opgetreden tijdens het parseren dichtbij %PDF-1.6
%��
1246 0 .
Regel: 4723
Teken: 21
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8080/ScriptResource.axd?d=pIR8OXvZoRojyW4g1LrIxQJ_PBSxowcac32J1wj6iuXDcoXm42o2_-RXqxdcfui11rd_ENAmsJBy6ZuWa6y59BIFz75plfDb9hceJY8IfLYyZk116lcE26DPuxB8-NB46RAswwOW4RN2EGnFK-0MTXrgj2R-IGGgcAS9lqbJpejfFHbU0&t=ffffffffdf4bca0c

Any suggestions on how to solve this type of errors?

Comment: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.

Comment: Could any of these common causes be the cause?

Comment: I'm using Sitecore CMS and the page displays in the Sitecore context. Sitecore has some httpmodules, but tracing was off. I don't know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this via AJAX through an `UpdatePanel`, you need to add the button as a `PostBackTrigger`. You can also add the button as a postback control in the code-behind like this:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(Button1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved it by adding the triggers to the updatepanel in the ascx file.